# How can I fix the error "Expected tag name, got “?” instead! (Html doesn’t support processing instructions)" in PHP? (I'm using CodeTasty.com)

Tags: php, html

I'm making a website for school on CodeTasty.com. Everytime I use `<?php ?>` I get the following error: 
**"Expected tag name, got “?” instead! (Html doesn’t support processing instructions)"**

The PHP code is also not executed.
I don't think it's because the code is wrong, for I still get the error with code copied from the internet.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: *Everytime I use "<?php ?>

Comment: Are you using `<?php ?>` in a `.html` file ?

Answer (score 3):

If the webserver supports php, change the file extension to `.php` instead of `.html`.

If the webserver does not support php, find a webserver that does, or use inline javascript if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had already done that and unfortunately it didn't work. We have to use Codetasty, we can't use anything else :(

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same error and **It got resolved when I changed the 'index.html' file name to 'index.php.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).